# Ошибка RuntimeException при загрузки картинки из галереи в ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на ImageView можно было загрузить картинку из галереи в этот ImageView. При тестировании на телефоне при открытии картинки перед ее помещением в ImageView возникает ошибка

```
public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 911;
    private String imagePath;
    ImageView ivEditProfil;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        ivEditProfil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_edit_profil);

        requestStoragePermission();
        ivEditProfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });
    }

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выберите изображение"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);

            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(new File(imagePath))
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(ivEditProfil);
        }
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader loader = new android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader(this, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Предоставлены права на чтение.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Права на чтение не были предоставлены.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    //Requesting permission
    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/download/21-54-59-photo.jpg typ=image/jpeg flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.halfway.yogamylife/com.halfway.yogamylife.EditProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3744)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3787)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.halfway.yogamylife.EditProfile.getRealPathFromURI(EditProfile.java:241)
at com.halfway.yogamylife.EditProfile.onActivityResult(EditProfile.java:227)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6508)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3740)
... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

У Вас `cursor` в функции `getRealPathFromURI` равен `null`, вероятнее всего `loadInBackground()` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Hombre, так оно и есть. А почему этот метод ничего не возвращает и как тогда найти путь к файлу?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38582681/8544322